# Replace all values in df1 with nan is they are less than or equal to the value in the corresponding column of df2

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to replace all values in df1 with nan is they are less than or equal to the value in the corresponding column of df2.

For example

df1:

```
 | A      | B       | C       |
-------------------------------
0| -0.1   | -0.5    |  3.0    |
1| -0.002 |  0.0037 | -0.06   |
2|  0.25  |  0.0048 |  0.06   |
3|  0.27  | -0.01   |  0.0055 |
```

df2:

```
        | A    | B      | C      |
-----------------------------------
LessThan| 0.26 | 0.0037 | 0.0055 |
```

output:

```
 | A    | B      | C    |
-------------------------
0| nan  | nan    | 3.0  |
1| nan  | nan    | nan  |
2| nan  | 0.0048 | 0.06 |
3| 0.27 | nan    | nan  |
```

In this example 0.25 in df1 column A was replaced with nan because it was less than the value in df2 column A. And so on. In my actual data there are 15 columns I need to check

I tried using apply

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x<=df2.loc["LessThan"] else x)
```

and adding df2 onto df1 and then using apply

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x<=df.loc["LessThan"] else x)
```

Comment: Typo: `df.apply` should be `df1.apply`, right?

Comment: Do you realize why the apply doesn't work? You're iterating over columns, not rows. If you fix that, then do you realize that "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous"?

Comment: @OCa I wanted to explain before but wasn't quite sure how to phrase it so I was hoping OP would reply to my comments first. Basically, it's too broad. Take a look at [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341) Breaking down the problem, I get **four** separate potential questions: 1) "How do I compare a row with all rows in another df?" (A: `df1 <= df2.loc["LessThan"]`) *[cont'd...]*

Comment: *[...cont'd]* 2) "How do I replace values with nan where a condition is true?" (which could be a duplicate of [How to replace dataframe column values with NaN based on a condition?](/q/53983563/4518341).) 3) "Why am I getting 'Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects'?" (A: You're iterating over columns, not rows.) 4) "Why am I getting 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous'?" (to which the answer depends on their expectations, but the solution could be `.apply(lambda row: row.where ...`.)

Comment: I see, thank you for the exaplanation and link. Yes, that isn't rare. So every time I answer with a method in like 4 steps, I'm not quite doing the right thing from SO point of view. Instead, I should somehow encourage to break down as one question per step. The path is not clear. I havent seen people help break down questions yet.

Comment: @OCa An answer that has multiple steps is perfectly fine. The problem is when a question is asking about a task that has multiple steps and no effort has been made to break down the problem. Like it says in the link, "a primary characteristic of a good question is that it is likely to be searched by someone else". Now, there is a grey area, but for me, this Q is well on the "less useful" side. What might also be confusing is I broke down the problem two different ways: the idiomatic process (1 and 2, corresponding to sugandha's answer) and the questions that follow from OP's attempt (3 and 4).

Comment: @OCa BTW, make sure to @-tag me (@wjandrea) so I get a notification. I just happened to come back here and see your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = df1.where(df1 > df2.loc['LessThan'].values, np.nan)
```

Comment: While this code does solve the problem, it'd help to add an explanation. Even a sentence or two would be fine, e.g. "You can use [this function] which [does exactly what you asked for]." I would also include a link to the documentation for reference. Check out [answer].

Comment: Why `.values`? Broadcasting works just fine if you leave it off.

Comment: Adding to the valid observations by @wjandrea: 1) apart from being unnecessary, [`df.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) is deprecated; *when needed*, use [`df.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) instead. 2) the `other` parameter inside [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) needs no specification: it will default to `np.nan` in this case. I.e., you can use: `df = df1.where(df1 > df2.loc['LessThan'])`.

Comment: Using `.values` is also incorrect if the columns date not in the same order.

Comment: @ouroboros1 `df.values` isn't deprecated. IIUC, it only matters when you care about what array it returns or you have mixed dtypes, so in this case it's fine (though as mentioned, it's not needed).